# Blender Internals to EEVEE?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, conversion

I have this model of starship enterprise all textured and set up. I wish to move over to EEVEE but heard that there is 0 compatibility between internal and eevee. Is that true? How can the model be changed into EEVEE engine?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before 2.8 there was addons to convert Blender Internal materials into Cycles materials.
But in 2.8 none of those addons have been upgraded to the new addon API changes yet. You could wait until one is upgraded.

In the meantime, you can simply make yourself a separate installation of [Blender 2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) and use its integrated [Material Utils](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils/) addon to convert your Internal materials into Cycles.
Then append the Cycles material into your 2.8 scene. Cycles materials are mostly compatible with Eevee, so there shouldn't be much issues switching from Cycles to Eevee.

Comment: It just... doesn't come out right. Specular mapping is all broken.

Comment: Please show us how it is so we can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

There are no major issues when switching from Cycle render to EEVEE render. But there are a few things to keep in mind like:
- Light (reduce the light intensity when switching to EEVEE, including the light of the world)
- Materials do not change much except glass materials. You can turn on "Refraction" to increase the reflection.
Hope to help you

Comment: You or I may have misunderstood the question. He is talking about materials in *Blender Internal*, a render engine in Blender 2.79. This would not be cycles.

Comment: I think me misunderstood. I start to learn blender 2.80, the first time I heard Blender Internal XD

Comment: Leander is correct. RIP.

Comment: Guess the user meant  **the default** engine, which in 2.8x is Cycles.