# Convert Blender Internal To Cycles/Eevee?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm wanting to re-render a project I made in Blender 2.79. It was made with Blender Internal, but since it's gone in newer versions, the project just doesn't look right in both Eevee nor Cycles. My project has white text on a white background on top of a white plane. I was re-creating a bumper from a TV show I used to watch.

Blender Internal:
[image]

Eevee:
[image]

Cycles:
[image]

Is there any way I can properly convert this to Cycles or Eevee? I'd love to get this re-rendered, plus get this rendered with a transparent background (with only the logo) while keeping all the shading intact.

Comment: Probably this could be a way https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152877/2214 ... if not (since) you use envy for lightning as well, you would have to set such effect manually (if you would have some issues with that share your file with us).

Comment: @vklidu I'm not really sure how to use this unfortunately. I have it enabled but I don't know how to get it to show up. Here's the blend. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xkPMpe8DXiWTTObYEsmhyIaawM8f_eT3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add some ambien occlusion in EEVEE and play with the settings, also turn on "space screen reflection"

Answer (score 1):

Under *Blender 2.79* there is an add-on *Material Util Specials* that converts *BI* to *Cycles* (see link in Q's comment), but it converts materials, your setup is more complex, more than materials it use environment lightning.

I don't think there is an one click way to switch *BI* to  *Eevee* or *Cycles* for you. So here is my adjustments to get closer to *BI*.

---

Mainly you use two **Point lights** and **Ambient Occlusion**.
There are a few things to care ...

Text object extrusion seems to be shaded only as *Smooth* under Blender 3.x (or I missed some setup) ... clearly visible on letter K.

[image]

To fix that, you can convert the *Text* object into a *Mesh* and enable *Auto Smooth* or for non-destructive way, you can just add **EdgeSplit**  modifier to the *Text* object ...

[image]

The main shading effect here is done by **Ambient Occlusion** ...

[image]

So probably you are already satisfied with this result, so you can stop to investigate further.

---

If you want to combine with light it becomes a bit tricky ... *Ambient Occlusion* is visible only when *World* color is set to white, but when *World* light is pure white, than scene lights doesn't affects result anymore.

To see the scene lights effect, you need darker environment ...

Spot_01
[image]

Spot_02
[image]

Notes:

- opening old (2.79) *blend* file in a newer version converts light strength values into overexposed light, so you have to manually adjust them to something like this ... for soft shadows change **Radius** > 2.

[image]

Don't forget enable **Contact Shadows** ...

[image]

Mixing the lights and AO together I had to set world color to  0.5 ... for *Plane* reflections set this simple material ... don't forget to enable **Screen Space Reflectio**n under *Render Properties*.

[image]

[image]

---

**For black environment** (asked in comment) ...

For Plane - enable Material Nodes and setup reflective material there ...

[image]

For propper reflection you should probably add *Light Probe* > **Reflection Plane** object (*Probe > Distance* 0.02) ...

[image]

*Ambient Occlusion* has no effect for black environment here (as mentioned earlier), so I disabled it and also Spot_02 light is OFF in this screenshot.

Comment: Late, but thanks. This helps out a lot. I made another version of this, but the background and the plane is black. Is there any way I could do the same thing while keeping the reflections?

Comment: Yeah ... I spent 6h to compare with 2.79, manage all issues there and present ... quite a lot for such "simple" thing. Especially I had to attach all objects into a new file (I could not figure out what makes all objects black even with a new cube). Since in a new file it was fine so some scene mismatch data.